# No output from pandas? I've searched a lot for a clue but no luck

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a file `pandaArrays.py`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([
    [1,4], [2,5], [3,6]
    ])

pd.DataFrame(arr)

print('Hello, World!')
```

When I run it, I only get the print message

```
$ python3 pandaArrays.py
Hello, World!
```

It happens for any possible pandas output. Nothing fails, there's no error, just nothing?!

Comment: On its own, `pd.DataFrame(arr)` does not print anything

Comment: Why were you expecting anything? Maybe you were looking at tutorials that use Jupyter/IPython?

Comment: Try `df = pd.DataFrame(arr) ; print(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the `DataFrame` object to a variable and explicitly print it. The `DataFrame` constructor does not automatically print the contents when you are writing Python code outside of an interpreter.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([
    [1,4], [2,5], [3,6]
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

print('Hello, World!')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jupyter and you want to print result of command `pd.DataFrame(arr)`,
you can delete string `print('Hello, World!')` and run it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([
    [1,4], [2,5], [3,6]
    ])

pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

And you will see your dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for editing and for comments.